# please explain this equation exactly

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

I have this equation :

```
I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:)));
```

where `I` is a matrix, I know that `min(I(:))` and `max(I(:))` compute minimum and maximum element of the `I` matrix respectively.

When I make a random matrix `rand(5,5)` or `randi(5,5)` I don't see any change before and after the implement above equation:

[image: two muppets]

but when I implement this equation on gray-scale image the result is binary image:

[image: two muppets]

Can anyone here explain this equation exactly please?

```
I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:)));
```

Comment: Karo, have a look at my answer. If you want me to say more about the gray-scale image I'd need the original image file – can you upload it and link to it here?

Comment: I do appreciate you  for what you have done for me dear @A.Donda  , does normalization impress contrast of gray-scale image  etc? normalization impect on which characters of image?

Comment: You're welcome! – I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but yes, this operation has an impact on contrast. If the image format you use has a maximal value range of [0, 1], then this operation spreads the gray differences in the image such that it uses the full range of that format, and therefore probably of the output device.

Comment: But that binarization you observed is something different. As I said, if you can post the original image file, I can expand the answer regarding that. Without that, I can only guess.

Comment: dear @A.Donda - my original image is   tire.tif   which is in the matlab software. how normalization can changes the contrast? thanks a lot  for your answers.

Comment: Karo, I added a section about that image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code line

```
I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:)));
```

linearly transforms data from the range [min(I(:)), max(I(:))] to the range [0, 1] – it is a form of standardization. The part before the division moves the data such that the minimal value becomes 0. Then the division squeezes the data such that the maximal value becomes 1.

You can get a feeling for what happens by plotting the original and transformed data against each other:

```
I = randi(100, 1, 10);
plot(I,  (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:))), '.')
xlabel original
ylabel transformed
```

[image]

By chance, the minimum value was 5 and the maximum value 75. The data are linearly transformed such that the minimum is mapped to 0 and the maximum to 1.

That you don't see a difference in your matrix plots is probably due to the way you plot it. If you use e.g. [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html), it does such a transformation internally before plotting (hence the `sc` part for "scaling") and so you don't *see* a difference. But the difference is there, just look at the numbers themselves:

Example:

```
>> I = randi(3, 3, 3)

I =

     1     2     2
     1     2     2
     2     3     3

>> I = (I - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:)))

I =

                         0                       0.5                       0.5
                         0                       0.5                       0.5
                       0.5                         1                         1
```

---

The gray-scale image that you used, `tire.tif` from Matlab, is an 8-bit image. If you read it into Matlab

```
I = imread('tire.tif');
```

you get an array of `uint8` values:

```
>> whos I
  Name        Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  I         205x232            47560  uint8
```

In Matlab, if you do computations with such an integer data type, in many cases the result stays an integer, too. You scale to [0, 1], but there are only two integers in that range. As a result you get an image that contains only 0 and 1 as values, a binary image. The effect can again be visualized by plotting:

```
plot(I(:),  (I(:) - min(I(:))) / (max(I(:)) - min(I(:))), '.')
xlabel original
ylabel transformed
```

[image]

The original data are integers from 0 to 255, and they are mapped to 0 for the range 0–127, and to 1 for the range 128–255. To avoid that, first convert the data to a floating-point data type:

```
I = double(I);
```

For more information on integer arithmetic, see the [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html).

Comment: your answers is great. thanks a lot dear @A. Donda  .